# How to Create a Module in dotnet Nuke in Visual studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dotnetnuke

How to create Modules in Dotnetnuke in Visual Studio 2010.

I have install dotnetnuke 6.2 version in my IIS 7.

Now, I want to create Module with Some database logic.

How can I create a Module in dotnetnuke as well as How can I show Dotnetnuke template in Visual studio installed Template in Visual studio 2010 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DotNetNuke Wiki has good information on [DotNetNuke module development](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Wiki/Page/Module-Development.aspx).